# C function "foo(LCHAR* value, size_t* len)" ... I need the text it returns as a C# string

Tags: c#, c, mono

I have some compiled C code which has a function that returns a string through a character array and an in/out integer which indicates the number of characters being sent back.  I need to call this exported function from Mono/C# code.

The C function looks as follows

```
/*
* @param value [out] The buffer used to hold the resulting value
* @param len [in/out] Length of buffer at "value"
*/
SOMEMACROHERE int C_getText(LCHAR* value, size_t* len);
```

The "SOMEMACROHERE" is doing the right thing, as I am successfully calling many other functions in this same library.

A JNI wrapper for this code employed it as follows:

```
static JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_android_getText(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz) {
    char rtn[1000];
    size_t rtnLength = sizeof(rtn) - 1;

    C_getText(rtn, &rtnLength);

    rtn[rtnLength] = 0;
    return env->NewStringUTF(rtn);
}
```

I do not, however, know how to call this from C# code.

I've tried many minor variations on the following, but have yet to hit upon the C# equivalent to the C code above.

```
// this one returns "" in buf, but bufLen is successfully indicating the length of the string the C code means to send back
[DllImport("libMyCCode", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal static extern int C_getValue (char[] buf, out int bufLen);
```

Can you direct my how to get this working?  Thanks!

edit:  This is how I got it working

```
byte[] cStringBuffer = new byte[512];

    public string getText()
    {           
        int bufLen = cStringBuffer.Length - 1;

        C_getText(cStringBuffer, out bufLen);       

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(bufLen);

        for (int i = 0; i < bufLen; i++)
            builder.Append((char)cStringBuffer [i]);

        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Why is this so ornery?  I want to post properly or delete.  BUT NO!

Comment: `internal static extern int C_getValue (StringBuilder buf, ref int bufLen);` remember to initialize the string builder with a capacity and pass this capacity as bufLen.